# Coroutines in F#

Tags: f#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm just getting started with Unity3D using F# and I'm noticing that [coroutines](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/07/unity3d-coroutines-in-detail/) are used heavily in books and tutorials as a neat solution for solving a variety of problems. I've been trying to figure out whether or not F# has the equivalent built-in constructs, or if it's at least possible to somehow mimic them, but I can't find anything on MSDN. I only found a few articles with implementations of coroutines using a Continuation monad, but these are way over my head as a beginner.

Here's the C# example from the Unity docs, which when called repeatedly inside the game loop results in fading the object's alpha color in small increments over time:

```
IEnumerator Fade() {
    for (float f = 1f; f >= 0; f -= 0.1f) {
        Color c = renderer.material.color;
        c.a = f;
        renderer.material.color = c;
        yield return;
    }
```

}

So I simply have to declare a function that returns an IEnumerator, then cede control wherever I want to inside the body with a "yield." I'm not sure how to do this in F# as I keep getting the error "This expression was expected to have type IEnumerator but here has type unit". The "yield" keyword also seems to behave differently in F# since unlike C# it cannot be used on its own and has to be inside a sequence expression as I understood from the docs.

So am I missing anything? How would the functionality above be implemented in F#?

---

### **UPDATE**

Gustavo's explanation is correct. Here is the exact Unity script which you can attach to an object to see it's Red color value decrease by 0.1 over a 10 second time frame.

```
namespace CoroutinesExample
open UnityEngine

type CoroutinesExample() =
    inherit MonoBehaviour()

    member this.Start() =
        // Either of the these two calls will work
        // this.StartCoroutine("Fade") |> ignore
        this.Fade()                       

    member this.Fade() =
       seq { 
           for f in 1.f .. -0.1f .. 0.f do 
               let mutable c = this.renderer.material.color
               c.r <- f 
               this.renderer.material.color <- c
               yield WaitForSeconds(1.f) 
       } :?> IEnumerator
```

[This article](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/07/unity3d-coroutines-in-detail/) was very helpful in explaining the details of coroutines in Unity.

Comment: Coroutines in Unity/C# are just IEnumerator's.  Try using your 'seq' keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx

Comment: Are IEnumerable and IEnumerator the same? The doc for F# sequences mentions that they're "an alias for IEnumerable(T)," while Unity wants me to have a function with an IEnumerator return type. Anyway, I'm trying to use seq as you suggested but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. Would you mind taking a look at my code? I've put it up here http://pastebin.com/Z0GE2Vy1

Comment: IEnumerable contains an IEnumerator. if you just need the latter one, you can retrieve it from the seq [=IEnumerable]

Comment: actually it would make sense that they just need an IEnumerator, as the only operation they care if I understood is to "go ahead one bit" and ont actually care for the returned value from that operation. so if you let x = seq{}  then x.GetEnumerator() you should be good to go according to this guess

Comment: @nicolas yeah I think this is the gist I got from reading [this article] (http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/07/unity3d-coroutines-in-detail/), although I'm still getting to grips with .net so I'm not sure if I understood the IEnumerable/IEnumerator part correctly. I did however try what you suggested by doing `member this.Fade():IEnumerator = x.GetEnumerator()` but I'm now getting the error "The expression was expected to have type IEnumerator but here has type Generic.IEnumerator<unit>"

Comment: @nicolas Actually it works! I just had to explicitly cast `x.GetEnumerator() :> IEnumerator` If you want to write up an answer explaining the C# part I'll accept it. I'm still not comfortable with neither my C# nor my F#. Thanks!

Comment: most of the merit is Gustavo's ;)   I imagine you can just cast like this ":> _" the compiler should figure out the correct type you intend to have and will generate a cast accordingly.

Comment: PS : this behaviour of no implicit casting is very useful in many situations and is the proper way to do OO

Comment: It's weird, leaving the compiler to figure out the type as in `seq {...} :?> _` is actually crashing Unity when that code runs. Doing an explicit `:?> IEnumerator` works though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent F# code is the following:

```
member this.Fade() =
    seq {
        for f in 1.0 .. -0.1 .. 0.0 do
            let c = renderer.material.color
            c.alpha <- f
            renderer.material.color <- c
            yield ()
    } :> IEnumerable
```

Note that unlike in C#, you have to yield some value, so we're using unit (`()`). The `seq` expression will have the type `seq<unit>`, which is an alias for `IEnumerable<Unit>`. To make it conform to the type Unity is expecting, we just need to upcast it by using `:> IEnumerable`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working since the Unity engine is looking for a function with an IEnumerator return type so I have to declare fade like so: member this.Fade():IEnumerator

Comment: Thanks! That's almost working. Doing the up-cast in `member this.Fade() = x.GetEnumerator() :> IEnumerator` works, but if I do it inline like you did I actually have to down-cast it with `:?> IEnumerator` for it to work. I'm not sure why. I'll update my code.

Comment: One more thing, the cast has to be to an IEnumerator, not an IEnumerable